# How to show Angulajs Pop automatically on the basis of some condition.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys I'm using angular toaster, how i can populate toaster automatically on the basis of some condition, fr ex: in my table I'm matching some characters if that character exists in my table's column, angular toaster should populate, how i can achieve this..

here is my code

```
$scope.set_color = function (row) {
   var inputString = row.Subject;
   for (i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
       var findMe = "call prepull ";
       if (inputString.toLowerCase().indexOf(findMe) > -1) {
           return { 'background-color': '#FFCCCB' }
           //toaster
           toaster.pop('info', "Hot Rush", "Found new Hot Rush");
       }
   }
}
```

i have added this in view

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000, 'position-class': 'toast-bottom-left', 'close-button':true, 'animation-class': 'toast-bottom-left'}"></toaster-container>
```

and added dependency in module and controller

```
angular.module('App', ['Services', 'smart-table', 'ui.bootstrap', 'toaster', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('PendingOrderController',
           function ($scope, $http, Services, $window, $timeout, $rootScope, toaster) {
}
```

how i can achieve this??

Comment: Please only add relevant tags. This has nothing to do with [tag:c#] nor [tag:asp.net]

Comment: at least they have angularjs and javascript knowledge, to add relevant tag I should get 1500 reputation.

Comment: Please put ``toaster.pop('info', "Hot Rush", "Found new Hot Rush");`` this line before ``return``

Comment: as you `return { 'background-color': '#FFCCCB' }` the code `toaster.pop('info', "Hot Rush", "Found new Hot Rush");` will not run putting `return.... line` after `toaster.pop.... line` should solve your problem

Comment: Thank you Devang and Jitendra. you are exactly right, its is working now..